# Listening to events from a control created at runtime

Tags: vba, excel, events, event-handling

I have made a class which, when given a UserForm as an argument, is supposed to place a control on that userform and listen to its events.

The simplified class is this:

#### `eventsTestItem` class

```
Private WithEvents formControl As MSForms.Image
Private parentUF As MSForms.UserForm

Private Sub formControl_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
MsgBox "clicked"
End Sub

Public Property Let Visible(ByVal makeVisible As Boolean)
    '(make) and show if true, otherwise delete
    If makeVisible Then
        ImageBase.Visible = True
    Else
        ParentForm.Controls.Remove ImageBase.Name
    End If
End Property

Public Property Set ItemParentUF(ByVal value As MSForms.UserForm)
    Set parentUF = value
End Property

Private Property Get ParentForm() As MSForms.UserForm
    If parentUF Is Nothing Then
        Err.Description = "Grid Item Requires parent Form to be set"
        Err.Raise 5                              'no parent uf set yet
    Else
        Set ParentForm = parentUF
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get ImageBase() As MSForms.Image
    If formControl Is Nothing Then
        Set formControl = ParentForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", Name:="TestImage", Visible:=False)
    End If
    Set ImageBase = formControl
End Property

Public Property Set ImageBase(value As MSForms.Image)
    Set formControl = value
End Property
```

which I expect to make an `Image` control whose events I can tune into.

To test, I made an empty userform with the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim testItem As New eventsTestItem  'create event listener class
    With testItem
        Set .ItemParentUF = Me   'tell it which userform to create a new control on
        .Visible = True     'Make and display the control
    End With
    Debug.Assert Me.Controls.Count = 1 'check if control added

End Sub
```

Which runs with no errors (i.e. the control is created, it is also visible on the form).

But the event listener isn't working as expected, the event should be raised when I click the image. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `testItem` instance is disposed of once the `UserForm_Initialize` returns.

To make it work, you'll have to store the instance outside of the scope of the procedure. For instance, you could declare it as `Static` to keep the instance alive:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Static testItem As Class1

    Set testItem = New Class1  'create event listener class
    With testItem
        Set .ItemParentUF = Me   'tell it which userform to create a new control on
        .Visible = True     'Make and display the control
    End With
    Debug.Assert Me.Controls.Count = 1 'check if control added

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that `testItem` is going out of scope as soon as the form is initialized.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim testItem As New eventsTestItem  'procedure-scoped
    '...

End Sub
```

Move that declaration to module-level, so that it lives in the appropriate scope.